# Labeling a plot point under the axis

Tags: plotting, labeling

This works well:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> Text[1/2, {1/2, 0.1}]]
```

This doesn't (the "1/2" label is not visible):

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> Text[1/2, {1/2, -0.1}]]
```

What is the easiest solution?

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> Text[1/2, {1/2, -0.1}], 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Scaled[.04], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"

Front-End: Wolfram Cloud.

**Note:** in version 9.0, you also need to add `PlotRangeClipping -> False`.

**Update:** An alternative approach using `Ticks`:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Ticks -> {Append[Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][##], 
   {.5, Framed[ToString[1/2, StandardForm], FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]], {0, 0}}] &, 
   Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Mathematica 12 gives using 'Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> Text[1/2, {1/2, -0.1}], 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Scaled[.1], Automatic}}]' a result which has only number "1" visible from the fraction "1/2". How to fix that?

Comment: I am actually not even able to reproduce your result, neither in Mathematica 11, nor Mathematica 12.

Comment: @wondering, it is probably OS-related then (I don't have access to version 11; but it works in version 12.0 Wolfram Cloud Front-End). You might want to add the version/OS information in your post.

Comment: With v12 under macOS 10.15, the `PlotRangeClipping -> False` is needed along with `ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Scaled[.06], Automatic}}`

Comment: Are you trying to *label* the graph, or instead just add a tick mark?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best solution but could be handy at times.

```
Labeled[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 1/2]
```

[image: PLot with label]

However, I should also mention that the label is not a part of the graphics.